# Dynamically Create an App through API? (This company is doing it)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

have read several posts that this isnt possible, wanted to share this video and also ask how they are acheiving starting a new application for a user.  If you watch around 1:30, you'll see Facebook is asking the user to create a new application from the canvas.  Any thoughts?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFfwBnrOXAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically

Documentation about create application api has been removed / hidden from official documentation and is really hard to find :(

Comment: It's also only available in the old Javascript SDK which was scheduled for removal on Oct 1 2011, so it should be shut down soon enough

Answer (score 1):

The video shows the usual workaround for the lack of App Creation API features: provide hand-holding for users and make them create the app manually, while they copy-and-paste stuff into the 'mothership' app.

So this company isn't really doing it through the API.

Comment: Look at 1:30 to 1:40.  User clicks ok on a dialog, and an app is created for them in the backend.  If its not the API, how are they doing that?